# mysqli_real_escape_string not working?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
if($_SESSION['s_logged_n'] == 'true'){
    $server = $panel->real_escape_string($_GET['ip']);
    $dn = $panel->real_escape_string($_GET['newname']);
    $query = $panel->query(
        "UPDATE `Registered` SET `displayname` = '$dn' WHERE `owner`='".$_SESSION['s_username']."' AND `server`='$server'"
    );
}
```

Above is the code that I am using. $panel is a connection to the database, which works. I've been banging my head for hours working with this stuff in order to try and escape the quotes.

Comment: so what is that $panel->real_escape_string actually doing? and what is your problem?

Comment: It is escaping the string, should be at least. It isn't actually doing it.

Comment: `real_escape_string` does not remove the quotes, it escapes them so that the whole string can be entered in the database. If you want to remove quotes, you would need something like `str_replace` or a regex. If you want to enter your quotes safely, you can also use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I don't want to remove them, I want to escape them.

Comment: @jeroen Is correct. If you look in your database, you _should_ see bare quotes - this is correct. The idea is that they are escaped only at the moment of insertion - you will not see escaped quotes in the db - the string is stored unmodified. If the quotes were inserted into the database without breaking your query with syntax errors, they have been correctly escaped.

Comment: you should really a) show the code of $panel->real_escape_string and b) explain the details of the problem, because it is not clear what your actual problem is

Comment: But then lets say someone tries to insert <input type="text" /> to the database through a form.. I then read that somewhere else. It should come up as text, except it is coming out as an input. And I know that $panel works. Its just a connection to the database, nothing special. It works in the other parts of my code.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() is the method to escape all html output. it is not related to database escaping.

Comment: Yes - the correct course of action is to escape it for html output with `htmlspecialchars()` in your application code. Generally you want to store the value onmodified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `mysqli_real_escape_string` you are using the method `real_escape_string` that belongs to the objects `$panel` now if that is just another name for `mysqli_real_escape_string` then it is not used to "strip" quotes, it is used to make a legal SQL query. Quotes are not an illegal entity. I would suggest simply `str_replace()` if you want to specifically target quotations.

**EDIT**

jeroen beat me in the comments :p